# Keyboard shortcuts on MS Office 2008 using Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to set up a keyboard shortcut that will enable me to set the font type when using MS Office on Mac OS X.

I have gone to System Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts and then Chosen Application Shortcuts.

Then I chose MS Office as the application and Font as the menu, and set my shortcut to be 'command + shift + d'

When I press this keys, it puts me in the font box in Word (which is good). However I want to set the font type and apply it, not just to choose it from a list.

Can I set an argument in the Keyboard Shortcuts box? Something like Font = 'Calibri' ? 
(I tried this and it did not work, so just wondering if there are other possibilities.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Keyboard Shortcuts Preference Pane you need to add an item called 'Calibri' for it to work. See my screenshot: [image] for an example.

Additionally have you tried using 'Styles' from the formatting palette? You can create and edit styles so that it's just a matter of applying that style to the text you select.